# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error” with Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, dynamic-data

I have a simple Dynamic Data application set up using forms authentication as the admin section of another web application. This works when I run it inside Visual Studio as a standalone project.

I've deployed it to my live site inside an application directory and I get the following error:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

```
Module IIS Web Core
Notification BeginRequest
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code 0x800700b7
Config Error Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'UrlRoutingHandler'
Config File \?\C:\sites\website1\dd\web.config
```

Config source:

```
<add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message normally indicates a "bitness" problem.

Are you running a 64 bit dll from a 32 bit application pool?

This would match that you only get the problem when you run it in the IIS app pool and not in VS.

Comment: Hi Shiraz, I am using everything 64-bit

Comment: acually I have same site running on other server and same config, its running well there, here its not is it a database issue, the pages using dynamic data are running well but there are couple other pages getting crashed are not using dynamic data.

Comment: It may be a duplicate UrlRoutingHandler in your config

Comment: nope I have only one UrlRoutingHandler key in web.config file and If I remove it my dynamic data pages does not work

Comment: But do the other pages that crash and do not use dynamic data start working?

Comment: Yes all pages which are not using dynamic data were getting crashed. But a miracle happened today I checked the mappings in IIS of both the server and added some required and removed unrequired The site is running perfectly well now. As I dont know much about configurations and IIS, I couldnt understand what happened. Thanks for all your help and support.